# how to "dig" inside XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to get to element in:
Xelement "Page" with property "ID" = 1, witch contains
XElement "Field" with property "ID" =1, witch contains
Xelement "textAndFont" with attribute "fontSize", witch value I'm trying to get :)

The XML code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<Page ID="1">
  <pageProperties filPath="filename" backgroundColor="Color.BLUE" MarginLeft="0" MarginRight="0" MarginTop="0" MarginBottom="0" />
  <Field ID="1">
    <FieldProperties elementWidth="100" ElementX="30" ElementY="0" fromRight="false" fromBottom="false">
      <background imagePath="C:filePatch" BackColor="Color.WHITE" transparentBackground="false" />
    </FieldProperties>
    <textAndFont conten="SIMENS" fontSize="10" fontFamily="Arial" fontColor="new Color(34, 236, 182)" />
    <textPosition PaddintLeft="10" PaddingRight="20" PaddintTop="10" PaddingBottom="5" VerticalAlg="center" HorisontalAlg="center" />
    <textDirection wrightToTop="false" widthLocked="true" stretchingStep="10" />
  </Field>

</Page>
```

edit:

My shot was:

```
 XElement xel = XElement.Load(@"xmlFile.xml");
     var prop = from propp in xel.Element("textAndFont").Attribute("fontSize")
                 where (int)propp.Element("Page").Attribute("ID")==1 &&
                 (int)propp.Element("Field").Attribute("ID")==1 select
                propp;
```

but it don't work

Comment: I think you forgot to post the XML.

Comment: Also better you post what trial you did to "dig" so far..

Comment: @Arkadiusz The XML file may have `Namespace` so better post the XML file here .,

Comment: is the first code (with xml source) visible for you? After your comments I really have doubts.

Comment: I don't see an element named `text`, nor do I see any element with `ID="2"`.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I meant ID = 2 (both times) and Field instead of text. I'll change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to go with an XPath-based selection of the desired attribute node, which nicely reflects your element hierarchy:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"path\to\your\xmlfile.xml");

var fontSize = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Page[@ID=1]/Field[@ID=1]/textAndFont/@fontSize");

Console.WriteLine("font size: " + fontSize.Value);
```

The XPath expression starts the selection at the `Page` element, then selects the `Field` element that has an `ID` attribute with value `1`, gets the `textFont` node below it and the `fontSize` attribute of that node. The return type is an `XmlNode` as attributes are just nodes in the document tree.

Note that strictly speaking the selection of `Page` with attribute `ID` value of `1` is not necessary as there can be only one top-level element in an XML file.

Comment: Works!
Simply Smart :)